# Best way to repeatedly poll a list to see which a job is complete

Tags: python, redis, queue, celery

We have a service that returns a `jobID` and the status is either Queued, Running or Complete.

Is there a library or framework that lets us add new `jobIDs` to a queue and poll the set of `jobIDs` to see which ones are in `COMPLETED` state. 
Then pop that `jobID` from the queue.

Celery or RedisQueue seems useful, but they keep running in background which is not ideal. 
Are there any simpler, light weight solutions to this that I can just plug in and use?

Comment: How about simply periodically polling the jobIDs?

Comment: I was thinking the same, use a redis list to store all the IDs and write a poll function in python.
It seemed like a trivial task, so was wondering if there is a well maintained library that does the same.

Answer (score 1):

Redis [LIST](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#lists) offers blocking operations. You can implement such logic easily yourself.

[BLPOP](https://redis.io/commands/BLPOP) and [BRPOP](https://redis.io/commands/brpop) can receive as many lists as arguments and it will return a popped item or block the client and wait until an item is pushed (or until your choice of timeout). [BRPOPLPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/brpoplpush) can move an element to a different list, but it can only monitor one list.